# Python: if condition changing value

Tags: python, if-statement, point

I have the following code that generates a `x_d` and `x_y`. I then want to add or subtract these values from the last calculated x and y (returned from `config.get_last_point()`), and store it in the latest point.

```
 def generate_asv_configuration(
        asv_count, generate_left_concavity, corner_angle=None):
    # Create a configuration
    config = Configuration(generate_left_concavity)

    for i in range(2, asv_count):
        # Calculate the angle to be used in the calculations
        turning_angle = turning_angle - delta_angle

        # Calculate the delta-x, and -y.
        x_d = MAX_BOOM_LENGTH * math.cos(turning_angle)
        y_d = MAX_BOOM_LENGTH * math.sin(turning_angle)

        # print generate_left_concavity
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            print '1: Left, i: {0}'.format(i)
            x = config.get_last_point()[0] - x_d
            y = config.get_last_point()[1] - y_d
        else:
            print '2: Right, i: {0}'.format(i)
            x = config.get_last_point()[0] + x_d
            y = config.get_last_point()[1] + y_d
        config.add_point((x, y))
```

The problem I'm having is that code generates an image similar to [image: this one]. That looks good, the different points have varying angles (you can see that some are almost closed, others are very open). However, when I change the first `if` condition to `(i % 2) == 0 and generate_left_concavity`, and I call it with `generate_left_concavity` to `True`, I guess something similar to [image: this image]. The problem is, there is really open polygons.

Unfortunately, I've tried a few different if conditions, and whenever I have `generate_left_concavity` in the condition, it always generates differently. I have even tried nested `if` conditions.

I believe I've even tried having the above two conditions, then in a later condition, I check `if generate_left_concavity`, if so, I add `2 * x_d` to compensate. It still generates the images similar to [image: this one].

I don't see how much of my code could directly affect the generation of x and y calculations based on an `if` condition, but I could be wrong. I can guarantee, however, that they are always entering the same condition branch, but generate differently.

Comment: What happens if you use `(i % 2) == 0 and True`?  What happens if you use `((i % 2) == 0) and True`?

Comment: When you create ```config``` does ```generate_left_concavity``` affect the sequence of points that it starts off with?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the difference between the intended output and the produced solution. Something to do with angles being too wide or narrow, I think. However, just looking at the code, there seems to be an asymmetry in the flow. `turning_angle = turning_angle - delta_angle` is always executed outside the conditional while inside the conditional one branch adds and the other subtracts.

Comment: @ScottHunter when I use both of them, it generates the expected output, that being the wider and narrow angles.

@wwii Nope. It doesn't matter if `generate_left_concavity` is `True` or `False`, the first two points are independent of that. However, the third point (i.e. the first in the for loop) is generated differently, hence the + or -.

@benrudgers Yup, you are correct. It should be generating both wide and narrow angles. I've just noticed that as well, the asymmetry is the same, I'll have to fix that for the problem, but I don't think it affects the if condition playing funky?

Comment: I've looked into a bit more, and it turns out that when I'm trying to generate a left-concavity open polygon, the range of angles that are possible are different to the possible angles for a right-concavity open polygon. Once I found out that if I find the min/max allowed angles for the concavity that I am generating, it was correctly selecting an angle within the bounds, therefore, generating the way I want :)

Thanks everyone for you help and guidance! I'm not to sure if I just close this myself, or? I post this as an answer?

Comment: @Brandon: You can, and I'd say should, post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked into a bit more, and it turns out that when I'm trying to generate a left-concavity open polygon, the range of angles that are possible are different to the possible angles for a right-concavity open polygon. Once I found out that if I find the min/max allowed angles for the concavity that I am generating, it was correctly selecting an angle within the bounds, therefore, generating the way I want :) Thanks everyone for you help and guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but:  If I think something weird is going on in a conditional, I try to make the conditional suites as simple as possible to eliminate or separate possible problem code.  Yours could be refactored:

```
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            print '1: Left, i: {0}'.format(i)
            x_d, y_d = -x_d, -y_d
        else:
            print '2: Right, i: {0}'.format(i)
        x = config.get_last_point()[0] + x_d
        y = config.get_last_point()[1] + y_d
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've changed my conditions to be like yours, it is quite a lot easier to read actually :) Even though it didn't fix the problem, I commented that above :)